# Autogenerate Markdown index from a recursive folder with makdown files in python

Tags: python, markdown

Hi I have a folder with many subfolders with markdown (.md) files and I want to generate an index for this. I try this

```
MD_FILE_LIST = (y for x in os.walk(DOC_FILES_DIR)
                for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.md')))

with open(DOC_FILES_DIR + 'index.md', 'w') as f:
    text = []
    for m_file in MD_FILE_LIST:
        text.append('%s[%s](/%s)\n' % (m_file.count(os.sep)*' ',
                                  m_file.split(os.sep)[-1].replace('.md', ''),
                                  m_file.replace(DOC_FILES_DIR, '').replace(os.sep,'/')))

    f.writelines(text)
```

But the generated file did´t show a linked html view, it's shown as a plain text `[name](url)`. as I shown in the picture
And also if it's possible create a heading at least for the 2 or 3 first levels

[image]

**NEW version**

I made some fix so now looks like [THIS](https://github.com/efirvida/OpenFoam-Documentation) here is my the updated version code:

```
with open(DOC_FILES_DIR + 'README.md', 'w') as f:
    text = []
    for m_file in MD_FILE_LIST:
        levels = m_file.replace(DOC_FILES_DIR, '').count(os.sep)
        if levels < 3:
            text.append( ' * ' + '#' * levels + ' [%s](./%s)\n' % (
                                    m_file.split(os.sep)[-1].replace('.md', ''),
                                    m_file.replace(DOC_FILES_DIR, '').replace(os.sep,'/')))
        else:
            text.append('%s[%s](./%s)\n' % (m_file.count(os.sep)*' ' + '- ',
                        m_file.split(os.sep)[-1].replace('.md', ''),
                        m_file.replace(DOC_FILES_DIR, '').replace(os.sep, '/')))
    text[0] = "# Index\n"
    f.writelines(text)
```

but seems that I can't use headings and list at the same time

Comment: what do you mean with `index view`?
Also, your code is really inefficient. You should change the `MD_FILE_LIST` into a generator, and swap the row with the `for` loop with the row with the `with` statement (and then change the open mode from `append` to `write`.

Comment: @Olian04, thanks for your tips I will fix soon in my code, and here I'm going to put an update

Comment: your output looks as it should, what was your question again?

Comment: @Olian04, maybe its the Typora but the picture show the generated html from the marksown no te the plain text file

Comment: you do know you are generating a markdown file? not an html file? 
This is a link in markdown: `[name](link)`, and this is a link in html: `<a href="link">name<a/>`. If you want the output to look like a website then you need to generate a `.html` file, not a `.md` file.

Comment: yes @Olian04 I know i´m generaating markdowns, because I want to publish them on github as shown here https://github.com/efirvida/OpenFoam-Documentation , with the last update my links are ok, but now I just want to use headings and links. its that posible

Comment: the syntax for a heading in md is `#`, `# hello` == `<h1>hello</h1>`, `### hello` == `<h3>hello</h3>`.

Comment: and what if I want to have a heading on a link?

Comment: guess... its not that hard. it only markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a blank line between each list item.

A strict reading of the [Markdown rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list) suggests that a block level element cannot be included in a list item unless it is a "loose" list, that is, it is surrounded by blank lines. For example, consider this simple list:

```
* Item 1
* Item 2
```

It gets rendered as:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Notice that the content of the list item gets inserted as inline text. No block level constructs.

However, this list:

```
* Item 1

* Item 2
```

Gets rendered as:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Item 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Item 2</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice that the content of each list item was placed inside a block level paragraph (`<p>`). And the only difference was that a blank line was added between the items.

This same technique can be used for other block level constructs. For example, to make a heading in Markdown, you precede the text by a number of hashes and at least one space:

```
* # Item 1

* # Item 2
```

Which results in:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h1>Item 1</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Item 2</h1>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now let's try that with the first few lines of your document:

```
# Index

* ## [combustionModel](./combustionModels/combustionModel/combustionModel.md)

* ## [diffusion](./combustionModels/diffusion/diffusion.md)

* ## [FSD.T](./combustionModels/FSD/FSD.T.md)

    - [consumptionSpeed](./combustionModels/FSD/reactionRateFlameAreaModels/consumptionSpeed/consumptionSpeed.md)
    - [reactionRateFlameArea](./combustionModels/FSD/reactionRateFlameAreaModels/reactionRateFlameArea/reactionRateFlameArea.md)
    - [relaxation](./combustionModels/FSD/reactionRateFlameAreaModels/relaxation/relaxation.md)

* ## [infinitelyFastChemistry](./combustionModels/infinitelyFastChemistry/infinitelyFastChemistry.md)
```

Which gets rendered as:

```
<h1>Index</h1>

<ul>
    <li>
        <h2><a href="./combustionModels/combustionModel/combustionModel.md">combustionModel</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2><a href="./combustionModels/diffusion/diffusion.md">diffusion</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2><a href="./combustionModels/FSD/FSD.T.md">FSD.T</a></h2>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="./combustionModels/FSD/reactionRateFlameAreaModels/consumptionSpeed/consumptionSpeed.md">consumptionSpeed</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="./combustionModels/FSD/reactionRateFlameAreaModels/reactionRateFlameArea/reactionRateFlameArea.md">reactionRateFlameArea</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="./combustionModels/FSD/reactionRateFlameAreaModels/relaxation/relaxation.md">relaxation</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2><a href="./combustionModels/infinitelyFastChemistry/infinitelyFastChemistry.md">infinitelyFastChemistry</a></h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice that I left the nested list (which doesn't have headers) without blank lines, so those list items do not get wrapped in paragraphs. If you would prefer paragraphs, then just include blank lines there as well.

The edit to you code is pretty simple. Just add an extra `\n` to line six:

```
            text.append( ' * ' + '#' * levels + ' [%s](./%s)\n\n' % (
```

as well as line 14 (while not technically required, it is good form to always have a blank line after a header in Markdown):

```
    text[0] = "# Index\n\n"
```

And if you want the nested sublists to be block level, also line 10:

```
            text.append('%s[%s](./%s)\n\n' % (m_file.count(os.sep)*' ' + '- ',
```

Comment: Now it looks more prettier ;) thanks!!! https://github.com/efirvida/OpenFoam-Documentation